# how to use npm/yarn in tsx react

Tags: reactjs, typescript, tsx

well, I am shifting to typescript for react. but the problem is that, when I install some package from the npm/yarn, I am unable to use it in my .tsx component. 
it says to look @types/ but sometimes, that package is not available
so, how can I use npm pacakges in.tsx file

Comment: [This article](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/setting-up-a-node-project-with-typescript) would be a great place to start.

Answer (score 0):

Visit https://definitelytyped.org/ and TypeSearch for the definitions of the package you need to run in your TS application.
This will allow you to use TS types of some of your favourite NPM JS packages.

Answer (score 0):

You can use it. The warning only shows because of missing type deceleration which you must install separately. Type deceleration are prefixed with `@types/`.

Some js packages already have type decelerations within installed bundle but some of them doesn't have. For those you must install it separately, if it exists.

Comment: @KanekiGhoul Just like js packages there is no difference. write yarn add 'package' and hit enter. Only thing you need for typescript is it's compiler

Comment: consider I downloaded any package

Comment: yarn add testPackage
so to use it on tsx
I use import {component} from 'testPackage'
but it doesn't work for tsx

Comment: @KanekiGhoul copy the package into node_modules folder. This is not the right way, however. If it is a local package there are better ways to install and use it and if it's a public package there must be no problem to use yarn add

Comment: @KanekiGhoul which package it is? The error you are getting is not related to typescript directly

Answer (score 0):

Some libraries don't have typescript support, so, before using it in your react-typescript project, you can check where or not they have typescript support in https://npmjs.com by entering the name of the package you want to use in the search box and put **@types/** in front of it. If such package is available you can safely use it in your project. In the below example, you can see that **lodash** library has typescript support. So you can safely run `npm install @types/lodash` in your project directory and use it.

[image: Here is an example]

Comment: what if there is no @types/myDesiredPackage , is there a way to use it? My many beloved packages are not in @types

Comment: Unfortunately, there's is no other way around it. Some packages don't release '@types' packages separately (for example semantic-ui-react library), though. They include types in the package itself because it was written with typescript. So, don't give up hope if there's no '@types' packages for your desired libraries. Read their documentation to see if they have typescript support.